# Adding computed persisted column to large table

Tags: sql-server, indexing, large-data, calculated-columns

I need to add computed persisted column to a large table (~1B rows). Can I do this somehow in batches or by using existing precalculated column?

I first tried with just simple column:

```
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[T] ADD [X] [decimal](32, 6) NULL
GO
UPDATE [dbo].[T]
SET [X] = [Y] / [Z]
```

After about 14 hours this completely filled 2 disks with transaction log and failed.
So I made this update in a cycle in batches - all done within 7 hours and no blocking to user queries.

Now I'd need this column to be automatically maintained for new records - hence considering persisted computed column. I want the downtime of the table to be as small as possible (ideally none). Looking at the experience with the simple update and batched update I'd like to somehow do this in batches or use the existing column (that holds the result of calculation) - is there any way how to achieve this?

I need persisted column as I need to index it afterwards and also because I'm optimizing query where compute scalar (of the exact expression I'm going to persist) takes considerable amount of time.
I was also considering indexed view, but I'm worried that same issue with long running transaction can occur.

Sql Server 2016 (Enterprise). Simple recovery mode.

**EDIT:**
For my future reference (and if anybody finds this helpful) - here's options that I considered (and tested):

- *Simple alter:*

`ALTER TABLE [dbo].[T] ADD [X] AZ [Y] / [Z] PERSISTED`

Pros: simple, integrity ensured

Cons: single transaction - huge transaction log requirements and if failed half way - all progress is lost; cannot be done online - any queries against the table are locked

- *Indexed view*

  CREATE VIEW [dbo].[T_view]
  --indexed view
  WITH SCHEMABINDING
  AS
  SELECT
      [Y],
      [Z],
      [Y] / (NULLIF(Z, 0)) AS [Z]
  FROM
      [dbo].[T]
  GO

  --first index of materialized view must be unique and clustered
  CREATE UNIQUE CLUSTERED INDEX IDX_T_view
      ON [dbo].[T_view] ([Z]) 
  GO

Pros: The underlying table does not get fragmented when adding columns

Cons: Mainly the need for uniqueness of the index. Plus also a single transaction

- *Non-persisted calculated column with index:*

  ALTER TABLE [dbo].[T] ADD [X] AZ [Y] / [Z]

  CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_T] ON [dbo].[T]
  (
      [X] ASC
  )

Pros: Quick, no table fragmentation (as no physical changes performed)

Cons: The computed column still needs to be computed each time it's been selected

- *Insert/update trigger:*

Pros: we can first update data in batches and then keep DB to take care of updating newly inserted rows. Column can be used in WHERE clause of filtered index

Cons: ensuring integrity is up on us (there can be some inserts/ updates in the menatime when we are updating table in batches)

- *Create new table and iteratively move data:*

Pros: Same as with trigger. Computed column is generally more performant than trigger; We can plan the data move in a way so that we get nicely defragmented table

Cons: same as with trigger. Plus we need extra space.

**EDIT2:**
After 2 days of moving the data building indexes I found out that computed column (even though persisted) cannot be used in where clause of filtered index. Even after I moved it from filter expression to include columns (so that SQL can still perform selection just based on this index), the performance degraded extremely. So I needed to convert to insert trigger solution.

Comment: One thing you might consider is creating a new table with the computed persisted column in the definition. Then you could populate this new table in batches from the existing table. This would minimize the downtime and blocking. Similar to the batching process you already did but in the end you would have a second copy of the data. Once it completes you would then drop the original table and rename the new one. You might want to consider adding the index from the beginning.

Comment: Another work-around is to create the column, populate it in batches, and then add a trigger that will populate it for all future inserts/updates.

Comment: @SeanLange - I like your comment - sounds like an interresting way to go!

Comment: If you follow the option I suggested you need to make sure you have enough disc space. 1 billion rows is not insignificant and could take quite a bit of space and it would mean you have a second copy of it. The extra storage space would only be needed until you drop the original table.

Comment: @SeanLange - sure - I expect to need at least same extra space. However - interestingly enough - it will be still far less than what the requirements for transaction log with simple update seemed to take.
After considering and testing few options I decided to go this way. If you care to convert your comment to answer (just copy&paste) - I'll mark as accepted.
Thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One thing you might consider is creating a new table with the computed persisted column in the definition. Then you could populate this new table in batches from the existing table. This would minimize the downtime and blocking. Similar to the batching process you already did but in the end you would have a second copy of the data. Once it completes you would then drop the original table and rename the new one. You might want to consider adding the index from the beginning.

Comment: How can this answer be the accepted one? Woo on earth would have a situation were this was an option? :)

Comment: @StephanRyer if you read the comments it was a suggestion which turned out to be the way the OP went with their solution. If you have a better approach perhaps you could consider posting it?

Comment: Ohhh sorry. Didn’t see that it was accepted. I just thought that doing so on a live system was never acceptable, but forgot that some case could actually allow for this solution :)

Answer (score 1):

SQL server allows indexes to be created on computed columns, even though the column itself is not persisted. Your computed column formula appears to be deterministic, so have you tried simply creating the desired index?

> You can define indexes on computed columns as long as the following
>   requirements are met:
>
> - Ownership requirements
> - Determinism requirements
> - Precision requirements
> - Data type requirements
> - SET option requirements

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/indexes/indexes-on-computed-columns?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: This is a very good answer!
One thing that I unfortunately forgot to meniton in question is that I want the column persisted also because I'm optimizing query where 'compute scalar' takes considerable percentage (~40) of the query. I'll update my question

Comment: @Jan A computed column can be persisted using the `PERSISTED` keyword in the computed column definition. That is of course only feasible if the column will always equal `Y/Z`.